# winform textBox not updating

Tags: c#, winforms

i've two winforms form1 and form2 as the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2;
    int count = 0;
    public bool fromForm2;

    public Form1(bool fromForm2 = false)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.fromForm2 = fromForm2;

        MessageBox.Show(fromForm2.ToString());
        if (fromForm2 == true) { 
            test();
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (frm2 == null)
        {
            frm2 = new Form2();   //Create form if not created
            frm2.FormClosed += frm2_FormClosed;  //Add eventhandler to cleanup after form closes
        }

        frm2.Show(this);  //Show Form assigning this form as the forms owner

    }

    void frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        frm2 = null;  //If form is closed make sure reference is set to null
        Show();
    }



    public void test ()
    {

        textBox1.Text = "ABCDFGHIJKLM";
        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Form 2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 f1;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form1 objj = new Form1(true);

        objj = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];


        objj.fromForm2 = true;


        objj = null;
    }


}
```

i want click the button in form2, will run test(), but i've found that, if i use if (fromForm2 == true) { } the if statement, the test() function will not update (redraw?) the text value to display to the textBox1, anyone know what is the reason of this?

Comment: Look at this point of your code: `Form1 objj = new Form1(true); objj = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];` Obviously the `objj` contains another instance different than the one which you created in first statement. An instance which is open and probably used default parameterless constructor of `Form1` which means `fromForm2 = false`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei how to solve the problem?

Comment: You are using the partial class and you can directly access the variables.  Try assigning the textbox value in string variable and access it

Comment: i've reconstructed the overall problem, problem solved